# Jest how to test if a mocked promise is waited to be resolved

Tags: javascript, promise, jestjs

My application code is something like this:

```
const promises = requests.map(async request => {await someAPI(request)});
await Promises.all(promises);
```

I don't care about the return value.

I have a mock for the API like

```
const someAPI = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
```

I can test that someAPI is called with the right parameters, but how can I test that the returned promise is indeed resolved? For example, if the client code is simply

```
const promises = requests.map(async request => {await someAPI(request)});
```

It would pass the test for calling the API, even though it doesn't actually try to resolve the promises.

I tried the suggestion, but this still doesn't work.

```
    let promiseResolved = false;
    someAPI.mockImplementation(
      () =>
        new Promise((resolve) => {
          promiseResolved = true;
          resolve();
        })
    );
```

When the method calls

```
const promises = requests.map(async request => {await someAPI(request)});
```

The boolean is already set to true. In reality, the API isn't even called if I don't do the Promise.all step.

Comment: "*how can I test that the returned promise is indeed resolved?*" - which promise do you mean, the one returned by `someAPI`? You don't, because you're mocking that method, that's not what you're testing.

Comment: Also, is these 2 lines essentially the same? Given the someAPI is an async function.
`const promises = requests.map(async request => {await someAPI(request)});`
and 
`const promises = requests.map( request => { someAPI(request)});`

Comment: @Bergi yeah, I want to test that my method resolves the promise returned by `someAPI`. I've wasted hours because I forgot to call Promise.all, which ended up no even called the API, so I want to make sure that I don't make the same mistake again.

Comment: "*my method resolves the promise returned by `someAPI`.*" - that's not how promises work. The promise is resolved by the code that created it (`someAPI`), completely independent from what happens to the promise later and how it is used in other code (such as the caller of `someAPI()`).

Comment: Can you show the whole "my application code", please? Is it a function that returns another promise? Can you show the whole Jest test you've written?

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the help but I just figured it out! It's not the prettiest but it's the only way I can think of.

Comment: @Bergi yeah what you said made sense. I meant "wait for it to resolve". My guess is that the API (AWS SDK) makes multiple consecutive requests to their endpoints, so if I don't await it then my function would be done running before it could complete all the requests.

Comment: Well there's better (and prettier) ways to do this, but I can't answer until you post these bits

Comment: You might want to change the title of your question then. Also it's still not clear in your approach how `let promiseResolved` is even going to be used.

Comment: Ok I updated the title and my answer. I can't post the whole thing since it's company code. This is as bare as I can reduce it, but I think it should be enough to work with :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out! Following @pawooten's suggestion, I created a local boolean variable. However, to make the test fail if the code doesn't wait for the promise to resolve, I had to add an asynchronous element to the mock Promise, like this:

```
let promiseResolved = false;
someAPI.mockImplementation(
  () =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        promiseResolved = true;
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    })
);
expect(promiseResolved).toBe(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a local boolean initialized to false, subscribe to the promise and set the boolean true when the promise is resolved, then assert the boolean is true, does this cover the test case?

Comment: I tried your solution, but I still can't get it to work. See my edited post!

Comment: Rather than setting promiseResolved inside the lambda of the mocked promise, set promiseResolved after the promises are actually resolved. `await Promises.all(promises).then( () => promiseResolved = true)`. This way, as long as your mocked promise is hardcoded to always resolve, your test will always set the promiseResolved boolean and will pass.